# Can we use "little" to mean like "barely" / "didn't + verb + much" / "didn't + verb + a lot" in sentences like "You talked little at the party."?

Tags: word-usage

Can we say sentences like

> 1) "You talked **little** at the party."
>
> 2) "I practiced **little** today."
>
> 3) "I ran **little** in yesterday's practice."
>
> 4) "Yesterday, I waited **little** for my turn at the doctor's waiting room." etc.

or do we only have to say these below?

> 1) "You **barely** talked at the party.", "You **didn't** talk **much** at the party", "You **didn't** talk **a lot** at the party."
>
> 2) "I **barely** practiced today.", "I **didn't** practice **much** today.", "I **didn't** talk **a lot** today."
>
> 3) "I **barely** ran in yesterday's practice.", "I **didn't** run **much** in yesterday's practice.", "I **didn't** run **a lot** in yesterday's practice."
>
> 4)  "Yesterday, I **barely** waited for my turn at the doctor's waiting room.",  "Yesterday, I **didn't** wait **much** for my turn at the doctor's waiting room.",  "Yesterday, I **didn't** wait **a lot** for my turn at the doctor's waiting room."

Comment: try substituting: did not x [verb]  much. The negative is preferable here in idiomatic English.

Comment: A good question.  In general, I think you can use *little* wherever you would use *much*, but in #4, *much* wouldn't make sense ("I waited *much*"?) and therefore *little* doesn't sound right either.

Comment: Note to my post: All of the declaratives with little are grammatical. They are just not as likely as the negatives with much.

Comment: I would happily use _little_ with all your examples except 4. The reason it doesn't fit with 4 is that I would use it for an activity that is, or may be, repeated several times during the interval: it means "on few occasions". I wouldn't use it to specify the length of a single period of waiting.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @ColinFine Do you think I can say either of these? **"You talked little in the previous class."** and **"You talked few times in the previous class."**? *Context:* Imagine that I'm saying those sentences to a fellow student who normally gets involved in the discussions in the classes a lot.

Comment: @FireandIce: yes, you can say either of those. However, they both sound rather literary to me, "few times" more so than "little". A more natural expression would be "you didn't talk very much", or "you didn't say very much".

Comment: Even though "You spoke little" sounds somewhat formal or literary, "You spoke very little" sounds quite natural and normal - at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

- You barely spoke at the party yesterday.
- You spoke little at the party yesterday. [grammatical]
- You didn't speak much at the party yesterday. [more used, also grammatical

Yes,I suppose barely can be used instead of negative verb + much and declarative verb + little. They essentially all mean the same thing.